# QT is fuzzing up my arc

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to draw a beautiful arc, but QT seems to be making it pix-elated and jaggy. I want it smooth, and I thought anti-aliasing would do that.

Edit: Using QT 4.7.4

Here is a screen shot:

[image: screen shot of MainWindow with jagged arc]

You can notice some parts of the Red Line (Arc) are relatively smooth, but get very ugly looking as it goes around.

Here is my self-contained PaintEvent. To test, just drop it into a template MainWindow GUI project:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QBrush fillBrush = QBrush(Qt::white, Qt::SolidPattern);
    QPen markPen(Qt::black);
    QPoint centrePt(this->width() / 2, this->height() / 2);
    int arcWidth = 8;                             // Width of the Arc
    int radius = (this->width() / 2) - arcWidth; // Radius is maximum minus width of arc line
    int maxSpeed = 80;                          // 80 MPH max speed
    int maxAngle = -270 * 16;                   // 80 MPH is -270, *16 for drawArc
    int speedLimit = 40;                        // Speed limit MPH
    double ratio = speedLimit / static_cast<float>(maxSpeed); // 80 MPH is max speed
    int angleSpan_ = maxAngle * ratio;
    int startAngle_ = -135 * 16;                // starting Angle is -135 for 0 MPH, *16 for drawArc

    QRect bounds(centrePt.x()-radius, centrePt.y()-radius, (2*radius), (2*radius));


    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true); // Suppose to smooth everything out?
    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
    painter.setBrush(fillBrush);

    // Draw the circle
    fillBrush = QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern);
    painter.drawEllipse(centrePt, radius, radius);

        //  Draw Arc
        markPen.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
        markPen.setJoinStyle(Qt::RoundJoin);
        markPen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
        markPen.setColor(Qt::red);
        markPen.setWidth(arcWidth);
        painter.setPen(markPen);
        fillBrush = QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern);
        painter.setBrush(fillBrush);

        painter.drawArc(bounds, startAngle_, angleSpan_);

        painter.end();

}
```

Comment: "You can notice some parts are relatively smooth, but get very ugly looking as it goes around." No, I don't notice that, are you referring to the red line?

Comment: Yes the Red Line is the Arc being drawn

Comment: have you tried this? 

`painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);`

You can have a look here too http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum

Comment: @slux83 I tried it, it seemed to maybe helped a little/stayed the same. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: One more question, regarding the starting and ending angles, they both seem to be 'off" by a few degrees, as expected, is this because of the width of the drawing pen or cap style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "relatively smooth" you are probably referring to the parts where the arc is a perfect line or staircase, where the result of anti-aliasing is almost not visible:

[image]

At other angles it's more difficult to get a result what would look fine on a low DPI screen, what's why you get these jagged smoothing:

[image]

There is not much you can do, besides applying some sharpening effect. But at the end you will get almost the same result as with no antialiasing:

[image]

However you can still improve the black line by snapping it to the nearest grid. You need to use floating-point versions of `QPoint` and `QRect`:

```
QPointF centrePt(this->width() / 2 + 0.5, this->height() / 2 + 0.5);
...
QRectF bounds(centrePt.x()-radius + 0.5, centrePt.y()-radius + 0.5, (2*radius), (2*radius));
```

Original:

[image] [image]

With snapping:

[image] [image]